# Will the feat Spell Sniper work with the Spell Shadow Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

Will the feat Spell Sniper work with the Spell Shadow Blade?

> **Spell Sniper**
>
> Prerequisite: The ability to cast at least one spell
>
> You have learned techniques to enhance your attacks with certain kinds of spells, gaining the following benefits:
>
> - When you cast a spell that requires you to make an attack roll, the spell's range is doubled.
> - Your ranged spell attacks ignore half cover and three-quarters cover.
> - You learn one cantrip that requires an attack roll. Choose the cantrip from the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list. Your spellcasting ability for this cantrip depends on the spell list you chose from: Charisma for bard, sorcerer, and warlock; Wisdom for cleric or druid; or Intelligence for wizard.

Comment: Which parts of the feat are you thinking of? And do you have reasons for thinking it should/shouldn't/might/might not?

Comment: What do you mean by "work with"?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov you've rolled this question back substantially. Can you clarify why? Furthermore, one of my edits was to remove extraneous information from a copyrighted source, the rollback has brought this information back.

Comment: @Pyro Presumably because we do not actually know what the OP is trying to ask and should not assume it to be any one thing. Also, the feat, in full, can be found other places across the site, and the fact that they have included the full text is *why* we cannot tell which part of the text they were wondering about. My current answers addresses the feat in full because the OP did not clarify what they were actually asking, which is also why it is closed

Comment: @Pyrotechnical The suggested edit was entirely conjectural based on no evidence whatsoever. OP needs to clarify their intent with this question.

Answer (score 4):

#### The Spell Sniper feat has absolutely no effect on *shadow blade*

Let's go through the effects of the feat:

1. Spells that require you to make an attack roll have their range doubled.

The range of *shadow blade* is "Self", so nothing changes.

2. Your ranged spell attacks ignore cover.

The *shadow blade* spell involves *weapon* attacks, so nothing changes.

3. You learn a cantrip.

The *shadow blade* spell it *not* a cantrip, so nothing changes.

---

That said, if, somehow, *shadow blade* is the *only* spell you can cast, then it *does* count towards the prerequisite for the feat, which is having the ability to cast at least one spell. If you can cast *shadow blade*, a spell, then you can take the Spell Sniper feat.

Comment: Shadow Blade does count as the necessary prerequisite to take Spell Sniper, though, if that's what they mean.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym how do you get the ability to cast a second level spell without the ability to cast first level spells?  Do you have an example?

Comment: Minor note: *Shadow blade* creates a weapon that lasts for the duration of the spell - so it's used to make weapon attacks, not spell attacks. (It can be wielded in hand or thrown, so it would be used to make melee attacks or ranged attacks accordingly.)